# How to avoid a double copy when implementing get API methods

Tags: c, rvalue

I Want to optimize a thread-safe "get" function for a variable `globalBig` that looks like the following

```
extern struct big *globalBig;    // points to a big struct defined elsewhere

struct big getGlobalBig(void) {
     // lock globalBig here...
     struct big ret = *globalBig;    // <------ copy #1 (into stack of getGlobalBig)
     // unlock globalBig here...
     return ret;                     // <------ copy #2 (into stack of caller)
}
```

When I look at the assembly, I see that there are two invocations of memcpy, one into the stack of the get method, and the second into the stack of the calling function caused by the return. I DO NOT want to have to pass in a pointer argument into `getGlobalBig()` because **I want a function that returns an rvalue** so that I could do stuff like:

```
if(getGlobalBig().someField == 9) {
     // yay
}
```

I am also aware that I could do a single copy by skipping the unlocking of the variable, leaving that to the caller as a cleanup activity, but this is undesirable as I want to spend as little time as possible with the lock on.

```
struct big getGlobalBig(void) {
     // lock globalBig here...
     return *globalBig;    // <------ copy #1 (directly into stack of caller, caller is responsible for unlocking)
}
```

So based on those needs, is there a way to avoid the two copies? For example, I envision something like "returning in advance":

```
struct big getGlobalBig(void) {
     // lock globalBig here...
     // single copy directly into the destination struct allocated in the stack area of the caller
     *(struct big*)SOMEHOW_GET_THE_ADDR_THAT_THIS_FUNCTION_COPIES_TO_WHEN_RETURNING = *globalBig; 
     // unlock globalBig here...
     return;      // return nothing, you already "did" (?)
}
```

Comment: The proposed solution would be non-portable. I don't think you can achieve this in pure C, but maybe with assembly code.

Comment: To _return_ something, a _return_ statement is needed, otherwise you are just changing the content of what must be a file scope global object.  And shouldn't this: `struct big getGlobalBig(void) {` be `struct big * getGlobalBig(void) {`  given that it returns `return *globalBig;`  ?

Comment: @ryyker That isn’t really the question though. In fact, there are definitely non-portable ways of achieving this, regardless of your point about `return` statement. — Regarding your edit: no. `*globalBig` *dereferences* the pointer, i.e. it returns a *value*, not a pointer.

Comment: `if(getGlobalBig().someField == 9)` The premise of wanting to do that should at least be questioned. You are trying to optimise by avoiding a double copy so it seems strange to accept even a single copy of a large struct and then use only one small field in it.

Comment: @kaylum fair point, in my app there are many structs of varying sizes and these get methods get generated automatically by a pre-compile script. For the large structs, I wouldn't use the rvalue a bunch of times in a single function to not overflow the stack. The developer would instead just set a a single local variable (or a global one) with the getGlobalBig() method `myBig = getGlobalBig(); if(myBig.someField == 9) {...}`. But this single getX() template gives the developer lots of flexibility that they can decide how to use with variables of different sizes

Comment: If that is the actual scenario then you don't really need to return an rvalue. You could pass in a pointer to the struct and have the getter copy directly into that. That does of course require slight changes to the pattern of the access but it's usually the case that flexibility and performance are competing concerns. So you may need to slide the dial to tradeoff a bit of one for the other.

Comment: [I only see one copy](https://godbolt.org/z/YxPhKM).

Comment: @KonradRudolph this will only ever run on one platform, so non-portable is not a problem

Comment: @CarlosVazquez In that case you can probably force NRVO (if needs be via inline assembly). But check out n. m.’s comment, it appears that NRVO is performed anyway. Are you sure your compiler doesn’t do this?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Wow, thanks! I went to your link and decreased the optimization level to from 2 to 1 and the second copy re-appeared. I then went to my own IAR C compiler and *increased* the optimizations from "low" to "medium" and the second copy disappeared. That's quite useful!